# Partial Fractions and Excluded Values

Tags: fractions, partial-fractions

So the way I was taught to decompose into partial fractions was something like this:

Say I begin with a fraction like $\frac{1}{x^2-1}$ that I want to decompose that into two fractions with linear denominators.

I would do $$\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x+1},$$

which then gives $1=A(x+1)+B(x-1)$.

Then to solve quickly, you can set $x=1$, and solve for $A$, then $x=-1$ and solve for $B$.

My question is, why can you let $x=1$ and $x=-1$?  Aren't those excluded values?  Isn't the equation $$\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x+1}$$ only valid for all $x$ other than $1$ and $-1$?

Comment: See also [How does partial fraction decomposition avoid division by zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/165118/242)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B$ be unknown constants.

Let $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\ne\pm 1\}$.

Then for all $x\in S$,
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x+1}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1=A(x+1)+B(x-1)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&A(x+1)+B(x-1)-1=0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Now consider the polynomial function $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$p(x)=A(x+1)+B(x-1)-1$$
We've shown that $p(x)=0$ for all $x\in S$.

But then, since $S$ is infinite, and a nonzero polynomial can't have infinitely many zeros, it follows that $p$ is the zero polynomial.

In particular, we must have $p(1)=0$ and $p(-1)=0$, which justifies the substitutions in question.